# Why did Yakov ask for a favor from Yosef instead of commanding him?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, funeral-burial-levaya, yosef, vayechi

Gen 47, 29:

> "וַיִּקְרְבוּ יְמֵי־יִשְׂרָאֵל לָמוּת וַיִּקְרָא לִבְנוֹ לְיוֹסֵף וַיֹּאמֶר לוֹ
>   **אִם־נָא מָצָאתִי חֵן בְּעֵינֶיךָ** שִׂים־נָא יָדְךָ תַּחַת יְרֵכִי
>   **וְעָשִׂיתָ עִמָּדִי חֶסֶד וֶאֱמֶת** אַל־נָא תִקְבְּרֵנִי בְּמִצְרָיִם׃
>
> And when the time approached for Israel to die, he summoned his son Joseph and said to him, “**Do me this favor, please,** place your hand under my thigh as a pledge of your steadfast loyalty: **please** do not bury me in Egypt."

Seemingly, Yaakov should have commanded Yosef to bury him in Israel, but instead, he begged him.

Why?

Comment: In 49:29 he *does* command. And the placing of the hand is taken to be an oath, as described two verses later.

Comment: @Alex 1. he repeats his request before the other sons 2. Why לשון בקשה and not ציווי?

Comment: 1. Yosef was present as well. 2. What does a command add to an oath?

Comment: @Alex Do you mean to ask why it was an oath instead of a command?

Comment: No. I mean to ask what would be gained by commanding him if he already had him take an oath?

Comment: It wasn't a question that Yosef would take his father to EY,rather he asked Yosef to take an oath to put pressure on paroh,so no command was necessary ,everyone was on the same page except maybe paroh.

Comment: The *favor* is the swearing of the oath, not the action of burying him in the Cave of the Patriarchs

Comment: I think @sam got to the main point. However, Ya'akov probably knew that even with the oath, there was no guarantee that Paroh would let Yosef leave the country. Keep in mind that Yosef was probably needed to fulfill royal duties. (Though, it's unclear to me exactly what he did once the famine was over.)

Answer (score 4):

[R' Samson Raphael Hirsch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch), in his commentary on this verse, reads the first נא as "after all." He suggests that Yosef had always wanted to use his power as viceroy to do favors for his father, but Yaakov had refused special treatment. Now, Yaakov did finally want one special favor, so he opened with "if, after all, you still want to favor me."

Taking this idea in a slightly different suggestion, I would suggest that perhaps even now, Yaakov was trying to avoid taking unfair advantage of being the viceroy's father. So, he approached Yosef as a petitioner to the viceroy, using appropriately obsequious language, rather than as a father to a son.

Comment: Like אב שמחל על כבודו? Being a father is an unfair advantage?

Comment: @AlBerko as in, nepotism